# No providers found restful api jeresey

Tags: java, rest, winstone

I am using `winstone` server with following java code

```
package com.spundhan.testweb;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/hello") 
public class Test {

// This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello SPUNDHAN";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello SPUNDHAN" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello SPUNDHAN" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello SPUNDHAN" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }


}
```

and my `web.xml` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com  

/xml/ns  /javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com /xml/ns/javaee      

/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>com.spundhan.testweb</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.spundhan.testweb</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

okay there is no problem in uploading code to server but when i am accessing the path  `localhost:8080/com.spundhan.testweb/rest/hello` in browser i am getting exception `404 file not found`. please any help out to over come this problem

Comment: I believe the URL should be localhost:8080/rest/hello.

Comment: That is a different question...

Comment: I didn't get what are you trying to tell , what do you mean by that is different question. Actually i haven't added "HELLO JERSEY" but still it displays that with what you told the path.

Comment: did you try to access localhost:8080/rest/hello as Sorin mentioned?